# Vuejs v-for set unique data

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that I can add when I click on the button.

```
<button type="submit" @click="components ++">add select box</button>
<div v-for="component in components">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control" v-model="customized_exercise.name" value={{exercise.id}}> 
        <option v-for="exercise in exercises">{{ exercise.name }}</option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

In this template when I add a couple of them and select a value,all the other components (select box) update with the same value.How can I make them have a unique value?

[image: select box value]

Vue

```
import ExerciseSelectbox from './ExerciseSelectbox.vue'
export default {

    methods: {
        fetchexercises: function(){
            this.$http.get('/api/exerciseinstructions').then(function (data) {
               this.$set('exercises',data['data'])
            })    
        },
    },

    comoponents: { ExerciseSelectbox  },
     data() {
         return{
             components: 1,
             newCustomizedExercise : {
                id:'',
                name:'',
                reps:'',
                sets_duration:'',
                weight:'',

             },


            numbers:[100]    

        }
    },

    ready() {
       this.fetchexercises()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I was also looking for this answer. I found that the Vue documentation mentions [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html):

> Inside v-for blocks we have full access to parent scope properties.
> v-for also supports an optional second argument for the index of the
> current item.

```
<ul id="example-2">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

So you can use this `index` parameter to set the id of each element in your loop to keep each one separate.

Or you can set the set your model to a name in the array. Something like `v-model="customized_exercise[index].name"`. But I haven't actually tried this option.

I found another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267205/vue-js-and-appending-a-variable-to-end-of-a-url) about how to use v-bind if you want to string concatenate the index variable in a data attribute.

```
<a v-bind:href="'uniqueName' + index">12312</a>
```