# Vue JS and appending a variable to end of a URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a v-for method on my page and I'm outputting a series of numbers.

```
1234
122356
124
12312
```

My v-for outputs each of these numbers and I need to append them to a link like the following:

```
<a href="/order/1234">1234</a>
<a href="/order/122356">122356</a>
<a href="/order/124">124</a>
<a href="/order/12312">12312</a>
```

I current get

```
<a href="/order/{{ order.number }}">1234</a>
<a href="/order/{{ order.number }}">122356</a>
<a href="/order/{{ order.number }}">124</a>
<a href="/order/{{ order.number }}">12312</a>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell what is in your templates ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should use the [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for this case, like following:

```
<a v-bind:href="'/order/' + order.number">1234</a>
<a v-bind:href="'/order/' + order.number">122356</a>
<a v-bind:href="'/order/' + order.number">124</a>
<a v-bind:href="'/order/' + order.number">12312</a>
```

or in short you can write following as well:

```
<a :href="'/order/' + order.number">1234</a>
<a :href="'/order/' + order.number">122356</a>
<a :href="'/order/' + order.number">124</a>
<a :href="'/order/' + order.number">12312</a>
```