# vue.js: Variables in attributes

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to concat a string with a variable within attributes with no success. I've tried this:

```
<div v-for="log in logs">
    <a href="{{'/log/' + log.purchaseId}}">{{log.id}}</a>
</div>
```

and also:

```
<div v-for="log in logs">
    <a href="/log/{{log.purchaseId}}">{{log.id}}</a>
</div>
```

All the links for similar issues are unfortunately already dead.

Comment: `<a :href="'/log/' + log.purchaseId">{{log.id}}</a>` this ? If it works, let me know, so I can explain It in asnwer.

Comment: Duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/q/41267205