# links overlay in v-bind:href

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I added dynamic link in `<header></header>` by the way mentioned in:

[Vue JS and appending a variable to end of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267205/vue-js-and-appending-a-variable-to-end-of-a-url#)

Here are my codes:

```
<tr class="notice-row" v-for="(myCase, id) in cases">
  <td>@{{myCase.name}}</td>
  <td>
    <a :href="'open/detail/' + myCase.id" class='btn btn-danger'>Go To Link</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The first time works fine, it direct to home/open/detail/myCase.id

But when I in `home/open/detail/myCase.id` and want to jump to another case, the link will overlay like: `home/open/detail/open/detail/myCase.id`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally used Vue methods to solve the problem.

Let `<a></a>` listen click event, and pass `myCase.id` to the methods.

```
<td>
   <a href="" @click.prevent="goLink(myCase.id)" class='btn btn-danger'>Go to link</a>
</td>
```

Vue methods:

```
 goLink(id) {
   let removeLink = window.location.href;  // get current link's text
   let repeatWord = removeLink.search('open/detail');  // check if there is repeat words 
   if (repeatWord > 0) {
      location.href = `../${id}`;  // other condition
   } else {
      location.href = `../open/detail/${id}`;  // first time click
   }
 },
```